# Jquery load function loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that allows users to comment on answers very similar to stackoverflow. Everything works except the writecomment.php which, ideally should get the questionid and answerid and place the appropriate comments in the right question and under the right answers.  My current writecomment.php code is wrong, but i really have no idea how to make it work properly.

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('document').ready(function () {
$('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');

$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        "url": $form.attr("action"),
        "data": $form.serialize(),
        "type": $form.attr("method"),
        success: function () {
            $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
            $('.commentBox').val(""); 
        }
    });
});
});



</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class='answerContainer' >
                    <p name='singleAnswer'>$answer[$f]</p>
                    <div class='commentContainer'></div>
                    <form method='POST' action='../comment.php'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='record_id' value='$answerid[$f]' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$q' />
                    <textarea class='commentBox'  wrap='soft' name='comment'></textarea>
                    <input type='submit' value='comment' class='submitCommentBox'>
                    </form>
                    </div>
```

writecomment.php:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';
$questionid=
$answerid=


$query4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE questionid='$q' AND answerid='$answerid'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)){

$comment=$row['comment'];
$user=$row['user'];
$time=$row['time'];

echo "<div id='singleComment'><b>$user</b>$comment</div>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Why `"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE questionid='$q' AND answerid='$answerid'"`? `"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE questionid='$q'` are not the correct way?

Comment: What actually is not working? Please update your question with more details about expected and actual behaviour. Are you saying that when the user clicks submit the new comment is successfully saved via the ajax call to "comment.php", but then within success handler the subsequent call to "writecomment.php" doesn't work? Are you getting errors (server- or client-side)? (And what is the "loop" mentioned in your question title?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **real** problem not in code, but in algorythm: You need to decide: will You use tree in comments or not, after that plan DB, only after that You should sit and write code.

If You will **not use tree** in comments, use 2 tables: 1) Questions 2) Answers

**Questions**

```
ID, USER_ID, QUESTION_TEXT
```

**Answers**

```
ID, QUESTION_ID, USER_ID, ANSWER_TEXT
```

When You need to list all answers by question use something like

```
SELECT USER_ID, ANSWER_TEXT FROM `Answers` WHERE QUESTION_ID = 123;
```

When You need to add a comment, just insert it to `Answers` table with QUESTION_ID field filled.

If You want to **use tree** in comments, You need only 1 table

**Entries**

```
ID, PARENT_ID, USER_ID, MESSAGE_TEXT
```

All questions will have **0** value in field PARENT_ID, because they are top of comments branch, all answer will have PARENT_ID=ID(of question), all comments to answers will have PARENT_ID=ID(of answer). For example

```
ID | PARENT_ID | MESSAGE_TEXT 

1  |         0 | How to make world better?
2  |         1 | Just try to smile
3  |         1 | Try to get a pet!
4  |         3 | I have a fish, that's boring!
```

That will look like this:

```
How to make world better?
   Just try to smile
   Try to get a pet!
       I have a fish, that's boring!
```

I hope my answer was useful for You, and You will leave $answerid behind ;)

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
var $form = $(this);
```

to

```
var myForm = $(this);
```

and every `$form` to `myForm`;

Change

```
$.ajax({
    "url": $form.attr("action"),
    "data": $form.serialize(),
    "type": $form.attr("method"),
```

to

```
$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    type: $form.attr("method"),
```

Change your PHP to

```
include 'connect.php';

$questionid = (int) $_GET['question_id'];
$answerid = (int) $_GET['record_id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE questionid='$q' AND answerid='$answerid'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $comment=$row['comment'];
    $user=$row['user'];
    $time=$row['time'];

    echo "<div id='singleComment'><b>$user</b>$comment</div>";
}
```

Comment: Why rename `$form` to `myForm`? Is that trying to avoid conflict with PHP variables, or...? Also, why remove the quotation marks from the property names in the object passed to `$.ajax()`? That should make no difference at all, and certainly has nothing to do with whatever is not working.

Comment: @nnnnnn Standardization. The problem are inside of answer's author PHP code.

Comment: There is nothing standard about your naming convention and quotes around js hash keys. Nor is it relevant to the question.

Comment: @liho1eye see jQuery manual. Which is the format used? `"url": 'action'` or `url: 'action'`? Now, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp and how it is named? `$myvar` or `myvar`? The second option for both. You don't need to do a downvote, because the PHP code is fixed and should do the job.

Comment: On contrary `$variable` notation is quiet standard for caching `$(selector)` values. Where as I personally would downvote your answer just for using `my` prefix on your variables alone. You also should read up some theory on data versus business objects, to better understand why it is preferable in this particular case to treat js object keys as hashtable keys and not object properties. But please leave it up to me wherever I "need" to downvote answer that has little to do with the question.